# How to use ICU with UTF-16?

Tags: c++, node.js, unicode, utf-16, icu

I'm looking into using ICU for Unicode string processing in a native Node.js module because it seems to me that `v8::String` (according to [these docs](http://bespin.cz/%7Eondras/html/classv8_1_1String.html)) doesn't have a C++ API for this purpose.

To my knowledge V8 expects UTF-16 in `ExternalStringResource` and other APIs, so I'd like to use ICU for UTF-16 processing. I specifically need to:

- Iterate over the characters (not just the 16-bit code units) of an UTF-16 string
- Tell the number of characters (not just the 16-bit code units) that an UTF-16 string contains

So I looked at the ICU documentation and found the [`UnicodeString`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html) and [`CharacterIterator`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1CharacterIterator.html) classes. However, `UnicodeString` doesn't have a `fromUTF16` method, only `fromUTF8` and `fromUTF32`.

The other thing I'm unsure about is, does the `UnicodeString` constructor copy the data I give it or not? I'd **very much prefer** to use a zero-copy approach where I'd just work with an immutable object so it shouldn't perform any copy operations, just use the buffer I point it at.

I'm also unsure if I can just use `UCharIterator` (assuming I can somehow convert `UChar*` from my UTF-16 strings).

So my question is: **How do I use ICU for the above purposes?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UnicodeString` uses UTF-16 for storage by default. That's why it only has `fromUTF8` and `fromUTF32`: from UTF-16 there is no conversion to be made.

It does copy the data. It is an owning string, much like `std::string`.

You can use `UCharIterator` if you don't want to copy the data. [`UChar` is a 16-bit value](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/umachine_8h.html#a6bb9fad572d65b305324ef288165e2ac). You can force it to be whatever 16-bit type you prefer working with by defining the `UCHAR_TYPE` macro:

> Define UChar to be UCHAR_TYPE, if that is #defined (for example, to char16_t), or wchar_t if that is 16 bits wide; always assumed to be unsigned.
>
> If neither is available, then define UChar to be uint16_t.
>
> This makes the definition of UChar platform-dependent but allows direct string type compatibility with platforms with 16-bit wchar_t types.

Comment: Martinho, thanks for the answer! :)  
Where is it documented that `UCharIterator` works with UTF-16? I couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: @Venemo see [uiter_SetString](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uiter_8h.html#a373dbf81553f2f3553b64c31e3c6147f). It just says it iterates over a "string", however the ICU API and docs often take that just to mean a UTF-16 string (there are historical reasons for this thing; ICU has been around for a long time). You can see that it uses UTF-16 because it takes a pointer to UChar.

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't able to find it in the docs where it says that a `UChar` means *UTF-16 code unit*